# Does code in aspx page get compiled in a web application?

Tags: asp.net

Let me just start by saying, if anyone knows of a good article that talks about this subject, please point me towards it.

Does code in an .aspx page (in between <% %> tags) get compiled in a web application or is it treated like markup where you can just change it without recompiling the solution? Does compiling only compile the code behind code in the .cs and designer.cs files ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're developing in a 'Web Application Project' (as opposed to 'Web site') then any change to class (.cs), code-behind file (.aspx.cs), designer files, etc (basically anything that isn't markup or static files like .htm) would require a rebuild in Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes, that much I know. I'm wondering if its necessary to recompile a web application project if you change code inside <% %> tags within an .aspx page.

Comment: No, <% ... %> are considered part of the markup and get dynamically compiled at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

All code within a `.aspx` file, in or out of code blocks (`<%%>`) gets compiled.

Changing an `.aspx` file will cause IIS to recompile it on the next request.

See MSDN - [ASP.NET Dynamic Compilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723.aspx).

---

Update (following comment):

As for development work - pretty much the same happens when you use the dev web server to view the page. You do not have to recompile the solution/project, but the page will get recompiled dynamically.

Comment: At runtime, but I think he was asking about needing to perform a build in Visual Studio before it works.

Comment: +1: This is pretty easy to test as well; Make a change in your .aspx page and hit refresh on your browser and you will see the change without having to rebuild your solution.

Comment: Also adding that although code in the .aspx pages is normally ignored by the compiler (until the page is requested at runtime), you *can* edit your .csproj file to have the compiler "precompile" the .aspx pages too.  It makes the compile step take longer, but it helps catch typos and similar compile-time issues before trying to view the page.