# How to add a aspx web page with no compilation

Tags: asp.net

I have an existing project in VS2005. When I add a new asxp page, the project is adding it as listed below

```
<Compile Include="ASPX\myNewPage.aspx.vb">
      <DependentUpon>myNewPage.aspx</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>ASPXCodeBehind</SubType>
</Compile>
```

I need to get it added as listed below.

```
 <None Include="ASPX\existingPage.aspx.vb">
      <SubType>ASPXCodeBehind</SubType>
      <DependentUpon>existingPage.aspx</DependentUpon>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
 </None>
```

How can we get it added like the above? What are the differences they can cause when I copy the file to production folder?

**REFERENCE**

1 [Does code in aspx page get compiled in a web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717076/does-code-in-aspx-page-get-compiled-in-a-web-application)

2 [How to work with code-behind class files in an ASP.NET application by using Visual Basic .NET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/312311)

3 [Understanding ASP.NET Dynamic Compilation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723.aspx)

**EDIT**

Following is how I added a page for dynamic compilation.

ASPX

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Src="WebForm1.aspx.vb" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.vb" 
    Inherits="WebForm1" %>
```

CODE BEHIND

```
Public Class WebForm1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
```

Steps Followed:

1. Publish it
2. Run it under IIS, pointing to the published location.
3. Delete WebForm1.aspx from the published folder
4. Manually copy WebForm1.aspx and WebForm1.aspx.vb into the publish location.

Comment: Is this specific to a Web site project?  If so try messing with MSbuild tab on property pages and check the "used fixed naming and single page assemblies" check nox. IIRC this gives you slightly different directives in as*x pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, in a web application, all code behind files such as `myNewPage.aspx.vb` are compiled into a single DLL. the file itself is no longer required at run-time, and it makes no difference when copied to the output directory except exposing your code behind.

To do this without manually editing the project file, right click your target file `myNewPage.aspx.vb` then select properties. Make changes as in the following screen:

[image]

**Build Action: None** - The file is not included in the project output group and is not compiled in the build process. An example is a text file that contains documentation, such as a Readme file.

**Copy to Output Directory** - This property specifies the conditions under which the selected source file will be copied to the output directory.

For more details, see [VS2005 File Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c6xyb66%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: You need to select `myNewPage.aspx.vb` not `myNewPage.aspx`